# How to split a string to multiple rows in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, arraylist

I have this dataframe:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|AttName  |x                                                          |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|Test     |{0, 0, 1, 0 },{1, 0, 1, 0 },{1, 1, 1, 0 }                  |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The schema is:

```
root
 |-- _AttName : string (nullable = true)
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
```

I want this converted to this:

```
AttName      x             id
Test     {0, 0, 1, 0 }     1
Test     {1, 0, 1, 0 }     2
Test     {1, 1, 1, 0 }     3
```

Any help on this?

Comment: What did you try that is not working?

Comment: Looks familiar …

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark explode/posexplode column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337056/spark-explode-posexplode-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe.show(false)
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|AttName  |x                                                          |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|Test     |{0, 0, 1, 0 },{1, 0, 1, 0 },{1, 1, 1, 0 }                  |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+


//First create an array by splitting your column
val tmpDataframe = dataframe.withColumn("tmp", split(col("x"), ","))
tmpDataframe.select("AttName", "tmp").show() 


+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|AttName  |tmp                                                         |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|Test     |[{0, 0, 1, 0 } , {1, 0, 1, 0 } , {1, 1, 1, 0 }]             |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+

// Then explode your array
val finalDataframe = tmpDataframe.withColumn("finalX", explode(col("tmp")))


+---------+-------------------------+
|AttName  |finalX                   |
+---------+-------------------------+
|Test     |{0, 0, 1, 0 }            |
+---------+-------------------------+
|Test     |{1, 0, 1, 0 }            |
+---------+-------------------------+
|Test     |{1, 1, 1, 0 }            |
+---------+-------------------------+
```